# CRM 2011 Workflow not triggered before mandatory fields are checked

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking to create a workflow that will populate any mandatory fields that do not contain data when a company is deactivated. The mandatory fields are either not populated because of legacy data or because the mandatory fields have changed since the record was created.

The issue I get is that the mandatory field check takes place before the workflow is triggered.

My workflow looks like follows:

```
If Status = Inactive
       If Company Name does not contain data
       Then update to ‘Test’
```

I have come up with a possible solution:

• Create a new button in the ribbon that runs the workflow on-demand and apply permissions to this button.

If possible though I would like to do this through a workflow that is triggered on clicking of the ‘Deactivate’ button. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation the record will not be saved until the mandatory fields are filled, and a workflow cannot be triggered if a record is not saved first.

An approach to solve this situation is to write a JavaScript attached to the OnSave event, but you need a rule to be able to identify the legacy records, so this JavaScript (that will fill the mandatory fields for you) will not run for normal records.

This approach is not tested, but with some tweaks should work.

Comment: Thanks Guido. I was thinking that with the workflow on-demand option ,that I have briefly mentioned above, would populate the mandatory fields and then deactivate the company (account). Do you think this would work? I would disable the other deactivate button so only one exists (the workflow one).

Comment: The most simple would be to populate the fields using sql but I don't want companies (accounts) that are active to have the mandatory fields populated with poor data.

Comment: an on-demand worflow will be the same, probably you can do with a dialog (wizard steps that in the end update the record) if the fields to fill are always the same